# Windows 7: Base System Device drivers missing

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers

I re-installed Windows 7 and I currently have 2 Base System Devices with a yellow exclamation which means it's unrecognized and the drivers for it are missing.

Windows update has been unable to find the missing drivers for the device and I can't figure out what the device could be.

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525. What could the Base System Device be?

---

***Here is a screenshot of the same***

[image: device manager]

---

**EDIT:**
***view by connection***

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Ricoh driver usually installs 3 devices, extract the **[Dell Vista driver](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=ie&cs=iedhs1&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R166188&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1525&servicetag=&os=WLH&osl=en&deviceid=13405&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=27&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=224384)** (e.g. with Universal Extractor) and look for the following subdirectories and install the driver manually via the device manager:

**xd**, **sd** and **smc**

worked for me on an Inspiron 1525 with Windows 7 32-bit yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Change the view to View by Connection, and then see what it's connected to.  That should help determine which devices these are.

I would guess they're SD media controller or something like that.

**Edit**
Did you update your chipset?

Be sure to install everything in the proper order, as listed [here](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/downloads/en/driver_install_order?c=us&cs=2684&l=en&s=pub&~lt=print).

1. Desktop System Software (DSS) or Notebook System Software (NSS) - A vital utility that provides critical updates and patches for the operating system. If you are reinstalling Windows or updating all drivers, it is important that this software be installed first. This is located under the System Utilities Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
2. Chipset - Helps Windows control system board components and controllers. This is located under the Chipset Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
3. Video Adapter - Enhances video performance. This is located under the Video Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
4. Network Interface Card (NIC) - Enhances the network controller for Internet or network access. This is located under the Network Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
5. Laptops Only: Dell Quickset or Dell Control Point Manager (DCP) - Controls power management, ambient light sensor, wireless profiles, and security features on laptops. This is located under the Applications on the Drivers and Downloads page.
6. Audio Adapter - Enables and enhances the audio controller. This is located under the Audio Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
7. Modem - Allows dial-up capability. This is located under the Communication Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
8. Wireless Network Card - Enables and enhances the wireless network controller. This is located under the Network Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
9. Touchpad, Pointer, Trackstick, Mice, and Keyboards - Enhances the pointing device features. This is located under the Input Device Drivers Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
10. Other Devices Intel vProTM  or AMTTM  - Enhances system manageability. This is located under the Chipset Category on on the Drivers and Downloads page.
    Bluetooth ®  Module located under the Network Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
    Dell Wireless Mobile Broadband Cards located under the Communication Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
    PCMCIA/Smartcard controller located under the Security Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.
    Touch Screen Digitizer Enables touch screen mouse control available on select Dell laptops. This is located under the Input Category on the Drivers and Downloads page.

Comment: updated the post above and it doesn't seem to be the SD media controller as that already exists

Comment: try installing the Ricoh chipset & the mobile chipset again.  I had almost this exact same issue, with the two unidentified base system devices, and it was fixed with the chipset update.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a 1525 and the only drivers I felt I needed to install were for sound and for touchpad. Everything else is quite fine with the W7 built in/findable software. While my system also shows the same yellow (not red for complete failure) notifications, basically if it isn't a problem, then don't worry about it. Have you had any hardware difficulties? I find this an essential attitude with Windows OSs, although not really a SuperUser approach...

Comment: i have been facing some unusual shut downs and im hoping its not related to drivers though the laptop hasnt done that for 2 days now but i wanna be sure im not doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

Ricoh R5C833
http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R161772&SystemID=VOS_N_1400&servicetag=&os=WLH&osl=en&deviceid=13405&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=27&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=216735

If you choose to go through Dell Drivers Home and use your service tag, these drivers will be located in the Chipset subcategory.

Answer (score 1):

Base System device : it is SD memory. If you install SD Memory You will be resolved your problems

Comment: not really I had to merely target the right drivers to solve this problem. True it had to do with the card reader on my laptop, but as I am currently using Windows-7 the Vista drivers have to be installed manually sometimes